# Geoserver importer task json file

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, import

I want to use the importer extension for the geoserver. I 'installed' this library and it works so far. My challenge is that i want to upload several shapefiles from a directory and I found this [example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html).

But every time I run this command:

*C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d @import.json "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver2110/rest/imports?async=true"*

I get this error message:

*Warning: Couldn't read data from file "import.json", this makes an empty POST.
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of*

For me is unclear, where I have to place the import.json file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have no **import.json** in the current folder.

You must create **import.json** with JSON like this (take a look at [the example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html)):

```
{
    "import": {
        "targetWorkspace": {
            "workspace": {
                "name": "tasmania"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "directory",
            "location": "C:/data/tasmania"
        }
    }
}
```